# nopcommerce 4.4 customization : Await methods throwing null reference exception

Tags: c#, async-await, nopcommerce

I am moving customization changes from nopcommerce 4.3 to 4.4. Nop 4.4 is completely built with async and await methods and I am new to this async await coding.
When I do simple method changes I am getting

> "Object reference not set to an instance of an object error".

I have created a simple method below after stripping other codes to show the issue.

Please let me know how to resolve this issue.

I'm getting the error at this line

```
var products1 = await _productModelFactory.PrepareProductOverviewModelsAsync(lst1);
```

[image]

```cs
public virtual async Task<WishlistModel> PrepareWishlistModelAsync1(WishlistModel model, IList<ShoppingCartItem> cart, bool isEditable = true)
{
    List<Product> lst1 = new List<Product>();
    lst1.Add(new Product { Id = 123, Name = "Product 1" });

    var products1 = await _productModelFactory.PrepareProductOverviewModelsAsync(lst1);

    return model;
}

public virtual async Task<IEnumerable<ProductOverviewModel>> PrepareProductOverviewModelsAsync(IEnumerable<Product> products,
    bool preparePriceModel = true, bool preparePictureModel = true,
    int? productThumbPictureSize = null, bool prepareSpecificationAttributes = false,
    bool forceRedirectionAfterAddingToCart = false)
{
    if (products == null)
        throw new ArgumentNullException(nameof(products));

    var models = new List<ProductOverviewModel>();
    foreach (var product in products)
    {
        var model = new ProductOverviewModel
        {
            Id = product.Id,
            Name = await _localizationService.GetLocalizedAsync(product, x => x.Name),
            ShortDescription = await _localizationService.GetLocalizedAsync(product, x => x.ShortDescription),
            FullDescription = await _localizationService.GetLocalizedAsync(product, x => x.FullDescription),
            SeName = await _urlRecordService.GetSeNameAsync(product),
            Sku = product.Sku,
            ProductType = product.ProductType,
            MarkAsNew = product.MarkAsNew &&
                (!product.MarkAsNewStartDateTimeUtc.HasValue || product.MarkAsNewStartDateTimeUtc.Value < DateTime.UtcNow) &&
                (!product.MarkAsNewEndDateTimeUtc.HasValue || product.MarkAsNewEndDateTimeUtc.Value > DateTime.UtcNow)
        };

        // Customization
        if (product.VendorId > 0)
        {
            var customer = await _customerService.GetCustomerByIdAsync(product.VendorId);

            model.FirstName = await _genericAttributeService.GetAttributeAsync<string>(customer, NopCustomerDefaults.FirstNameAttribute);
            model.LastName = await _genericAttributeService.GetAttributeAsync<string>(customer, NopCustomerDefaults.LastNameAttribute);
            model.Phone = await _genericAttributeService.GetAttributeAsync<string>(customer, NopCustomerDefaults.PhoneAttribute);

            model.Gender = await _genericAttributeService.GetAttributeAsync<string>(customer, NopCustomerDefaults.GenderAttribute);
            model.Company = await _genericAttributeService.GetAttributeAsync<string>(customer, NopCustomerDefaults.CompanyAttribute);
            model.CountryId = await _genericAttributeService.GetAttributeAsync<string>(customer, NopCustomerDefaults.CountryIdAttribute);

            model.StateProvinceId = await _genericAttributeService.GetAttributeAsync<string>(customer, NopCustomerDefaults.StateProvinceIdAttribute);
            model.LanguageId = await _genericAttributeService.GetAttributeAsync<string>(customer, NopCustomerDefaults.LanguageIdAttribute);
            model.TimeZoneId = await _genericAttributeService.GetAttributeAsync<string>(customer, NopCustomerDefaults.TimeZoneIdAttribute);
            model.AvatarPictureId = await _genericAttributeService.GetAttributeAsync<string>(customer, NopCustomerDefaults.AvatarPictureIdAttribute);

            model.CustomerProfileTypeId = model.FirstName;
        }

        //price
        if (preparePriceModel)
        {
            model.ProductPrice = await PrepareProductOverviewPriceModelAsync(product, forceRedirectionAfterAddingToCart);
        }

        //picture
        if (preparePictureModel)
        {
            model.DefaultPictureModel = await PrepareProductOverviewPictureModelAsync(product, productThumbPictureSize);
        }

        //specs
        if (prepareSpecificationAttributes)
        {
            model.ProductSpecificationModel = await PrepareProductSpecificationModelAsync(product);
        }

        //reviews
        model.ReviewOverviewModel = await PrepareProductReviewOverviewModelAsync(product);

        models.Add(model);
    }

    return models;
}
```

Comment: try putting breakpoint inside `PrepareProductOverviewModelsAsync` method and debug though it

Comment: You should check the properties of the exception using the pop-up you show in the image. It will provide you a line number. It could be that the _productModelFactory is null, for instance. You need to dig a bit more, it doesn't seem related to the async clause anyway.

Comment: Can you share detailed error from Admin > System >Log ?